# Files in directory not in order

Tags: php, file

I use this code to list all files in directory:

```
$d = dir($FolderToPlay);
while (($file = $d->read()) !== false){
...
...
}
$d->close();
```

But, the result is not in the numerical order. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `glob()` to get a list of all the filenames, then use `sort()` to sort it however you like.

Comment: You asked the same exact question yesterday. Why did you post a new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627359/sort-files-by-type-and-serial-number

Comment: I was not answered and closed, sorry

Comment: You're not supposed to re-ask questions, sorry. Next time, you should edit your original question if possible to get it reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of all the filenames, then you can use a sorting function.

```
$d = glob("$FolderToPlay/*");
natsort($d);
foreach ($d as $file) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean foreach?

Comment: And I didn't understand how to extract all files like .wav

Comment: Change `*` to `*.wav`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to list all files in a directory is with scarndir() fuction.
You can use it like this:

```
//Create a variable that contains all your files 
$root = scandir($dir);
//Do something with each value, like push them into an array, do regex etc.
foreach($root as $value){
//...
}
```